# Show that the set of all vectors in $S$ with non-negative components is a generating set.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$S = \{(x_1, ... ,x_n ) : x_1 = ... = x_m = 0\}$ for any fixed $m,\ 1 \leq m < n$

Show that the set of all vectors in $S$ with non-negative components is a generating set.

According to my proof set of all vectors is in generating set. How can I restrict my proof to only the set of non-negative components?

Comment: My bad. It was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that every vector $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ with $x_1 = \cdots = x_m = 0$ for some integer $1 \leq m \leq n - 1$ can be written as $x_1 \mathbf e_1 + \cdots + x_n \mathbf e_n,$ where the vectors $\mathbf e_i$ have a $1$ in the $i$th place and $0$s elsewhere. (One other way of saying this is that the $j$th entry of $\mathbf e_i$ is the Kronecker delta $\delta_{ij}.$) Consequently, the set $E = \{\mathbf e_1, \dots, \mathbf e_n \}$ generates $S.$ Consider the set $N$ of all vectors in $S$ with non-negative components. Certainly, the set $E \cup N$ generates $S,$ as $E$ alone generates $S.$ But in view of the fact that $E \subseteq N,$ we have that $E \cup N = N,$ hence $N$ generates $S,$ as desired. QED.